Correctly sizing RecyclerView's children
I have a RecyclerView declared this way :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mypackage.myRecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyRecyclerViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp">
</mypackage.myRecyclerView>

Children are built this way :



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/myBorder"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myBorder"/>

I'm expecting the second field to fill all the remaining space left in my RecyclerView, thanks to it's match_parent android:layout_width property, but it's not the case!
If I add a background color to my RecyclerView, I see it correctly reach my screen's right hand end, but my second TextView curiously ends approximately in it's middle.
Any idea to make my second TextView use all the available space?
The LayoutManager I use is a 2 columned GridLayoutManager.
Here's the screenshot of why I get :

The grey area at the right shows how large the RecyclerView is. As you can see, the second TextView stops too soon, leaving a lot of empty space unused. What I want to do is to have this TextView take benefit from all this empty space.

you should give some screenshots to show what you mean

@Zelig share a screenshot of what you have currently and what you’re trying to achieve.

Solution found! I was misunderstanding the spanCount parameter. Thought it was representing the number of colums lines in the RecyclerViewcontain. By creating my GridLayoutManager with a spanCountset to 1, my `RecyclerView's behaviour is as expected!

As you can see in the screenshot, when spancount is set to two, I have two children displayed on the same line, and that's why the child I wanted to take all the available space only takes half of it.

Use the layout_weight property so it takes all the empty space like this 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myBorder"/>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
